# next-auth prisma adapter and credentials provider, session is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I've implemented login using a password with next.js and next-auth. After logging in, I can retrieve the session and everything works as expected.

However, when I add the Prisma adapter like so:

```
adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma)
```

Fetching the session on the server side using:

```
const session = await getServerSession(authOptions)
```

returns null, and the tables created by Prisma for "user" and "session" are empty.

If I understand correctly, this happens because after adding the adapter to next-auth, it now checks the session in the database. If it doesn't exist, it returns null. But logging in with a username and password (credentials) doesn't add anything to this database, which is intentional as per the documentation to encourage people to move away from using passwords. So, if I want to combine OAuth handling with the adapter, and also support traditional passwords, do I need to manually add sessions and 'user' accounts to the Prisma database when logging in with a password? Or should I create a separate table for users logging in through credentials?

and yes i using jwt token, but still need store all information in database

Comment: Did you solve this? I’m having the same problem and questions.